# Why isn't the following ellipsis/truncate function cutting the strings in the same length?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this function to cut strings in a certain length and add `...` at the end:

```
ellipsis (string, threshold) {
  if (string.length > threshold) return string.substring(0, threshold) + '...'
  else return string
},
```

Usage: `ellipsis(string, 35)`

Sample strings:

```
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890

4567896 7890456 8904567 
 89456789456789456789456789456789456789456789456789456789456789
```

Result:

```
12345678901234567890123456789012...

4567896 7890456 8904567 
 894567...
```

As you can see the second string ends up being shorter.

How to modify this ellipsis function so the two strings end up the same length even if they have spaces and new lines?

**EDIT:**

> original: 4567896 7890456 8904567 
>   89456789456789456789456789456789456789456789456789456789456789
>
> replaced: 4567896 7890456 8904567 
>   89456789456789456789456789456789456789456789456789456789456789

Comment: AS i can see, the second string got an  new line, and cut in this. This is true?

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón Yes you are right.

Comment: so makes fine the ellipsis, given in consideration the new line. Other thing is that you remove new lines before ellipsis, this is what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing Dom string variable not have break .try with `replace()` new line

```js
function ellipsis(string, threshold) {
  if (string.length > threshold) {
    return (string.substring(0, threshold) + '...').replace(/\\n/g,'').trim()
  } else {
    return string
  }
}

var string1 = '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890';
console.log(ellipsis(string1, 35))


var string2 = '4567896 7890456 8904567  89456789456789456789456789456789456789456789456789456789456789';
console.log(ellipsis(string2, 35))
```

**updated**
you could expand your `console.log` .its not have any break

[image]

Comment: I think the `.replace` part isn't modifying the strings. Please see my **EDIT**

Comment: Where did you get like this..in your `console.log` or `html element` provide some working level code

Comment: Yes, I got it in my console log.

Comment: you just expand your console.log box see my updated answer image